# iOS apps without developer account or adhoc

Tags: ios

I'm creating apps with Flash CS5. So I've this AIR app I'ld like to create an iPhone app from just for some friends. I don't want to get a developer account or any other account like adhoc from Apple.

Is it possible to make an iPhone app and get it on the device without Jailbreaking it?

Thanks

Comment: Get $10 from ten friends.  Then you can distribute the app thru adhoc to 100 devices.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no.  Native applications must be signed by a developer certificate before they're allowed to be installed on non-jailbroken devices.

The closest you can get is to develop a HTML5/CSS/JavaScript application that can be used in mobile Safari.  You have access to quite a few APIs still though (offline data storage, geolocation, orientation, etc).

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way Apple would allow that.